# Custom Authorize attribute not working on expired ajax requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms-authentication

I have a custom authorize attribute on my controllers and it is not being called on expired ajax requests. 
I'm using forms authentication, and call controller methods via $.ajax (jQuery). The ajax request returns my login page and I don't seem to be able to intercept this.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
I figured out why: I commented the authorization section in my web.config like follows:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Login" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="false"/>
    </authentication>
    <!--<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>-->
```

Now my authorization filter is being called even after expiration. Turns out that Web.config authorization rules take precedence over Authorize filters.

Comment: I spent three hours racking my brain on this one. Didn't even think about commenting out the code. Worked great for MVC 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return 401 unauthorized. ASP.NET intercepts that and redirects to the login page defined in web.config. For AJAX, instead return something else, like 403.

Comment: For whatever reason AuthorizeCore (overriden) isn't even  being called... I'm trying to figure out what could prevent it.

Comment: +1 Its awfull, that asp.net picks up the 401 and redirects automatically. This is a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a good blog on this over here:

https://www.trycatchfail.com/2011/01/17/handling-authorization-failures-for-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Use `context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to detect if request is an Ajax request or not.
Check more here:

[Authorize attribute and jquery AJAX in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)