# Javascript - When a button is clicked, redirect to Login page if not authenticated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I inherited an MVC app with jQuery and Kendo. Most of the controller actions have the [Authorize] attribute and it handles the redirection to the Login page nicely if the user is not already authenticated.

However, there's one feature that requires some additional information before the action is invoked. So, when the button for that feature is clicked, a Kendo window is displayed asking the user for a DateTime input. Then the action is called with that extra piece of input data, and the user is sent to another page after the action completes with the result of that action.

Here's the simplified code flow:

```
btnClicked_Listener{
    // Pop-up Kendo window for DateTime input
    // Get URL for action (@Url.Action("MyAction1", "MyController", new { date = [DateTime input] })

    $.ajax({
    datatype: 'json',
    url: finalUrl,
    cache: false,

    success: function (result) {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/MyController/MyAction2?planId=' + result;

    },

    error: function (xhr, error, message) {
        handleError(xhr, error, message);
    }
});
```

This works fine if the user is already logged in. But if the user is not already logged in, here's what happens:

- Kendo window popups for DateTime input.
- Login page is displayed (since MyAction1 has the [Authorize] attribute).
- User logs in.
- Page '/MyController/MyAction2?planId=' is invalid, since MyAction1 never gets hit, and so result=null.

How can I fix this where the Javascript code can detect whether the user is logged in or not, and direct him to the Login page instead?

I do not want to hide the button if the user is not authenticated. I want to let the user be able to click on the button, but get redirected instead.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The simplest way that I've run into is to create a new authorization attribute for ajax requests that returns a status upon failure, then in your javascript, handle the response. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/11085769#11085769) for details.

Comment: If the user is not logged in why not add the authorize attribute to the action that invokes this view. Surely then at this point you don't need to worry about the additional content passed by your javascript method. Maybe I am misreading your question so apologies if that is the case.

Comment: @DavidShorthose: I presume I can do that, but it doesn't quite fit the business requirement. It's one of those pages that are supposed to be visible anonymously (e.g. display all products you have in your store), and when the user wants to purchase it, then they need an account. If you force them to log in too early, they might not even be interested in what you have to offer at all.

Comment: @AngieM - just a quick and dirty way.  Could you store the planId in a session or a cookie or a viewbag?

Comment: @webdad3: I'm not sure how to accomplish it. When I debugged the code, it basically loads the Log In page, then goes straight to '/MyController/MyAction2?planId='. It never calls MyAction1, which in the working scenario, will return the planId (XXXX) to feed into MyAction2?planId=XXXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix server side code and javascript code to checking weather user is logged in or not.

```
<script>
    btnClicked_Listener
    {
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <text>
                // Pop-up Kendo window for DateTime input
                // Get URL for action (@Url.Action("MyAction1", "MyController", new {date = [DateTime input]})
                    $.ajax({
                        datatype: 'json',
                        url: finalUrl,
                        cache: false,

                        success: function (result) {
                            window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/MyController/MyAction2?planId=' + result;

                        },

                        error: function (xhr, error, message) {
                            handleError(xhr, error, message);
                        }
                    });
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text> window.location.href = 'Login page url' </text>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Edit: If you want pus your JS code in external file you have to put your code inside a function then pass a bool value to the function which indicate whether user is authenticated or not.

External JS

```
function handleButtonClick(isAuthenticated) {
    btnClicked_Listener
    {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            // Pop-up Kendo window for DateTime input
            // Get URL for action (@Url.Action("MyAction1", "MyController", new {date = [DateTime input]})
            $.ajax({
                datatype: 'json',
                url: finalUrl,
                cache: false,

                success: function(result) {
                    window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/MyController/MyAction2?planId=' + result;

                },

                error: function(xhr, error, message) {
                    handleError(xhr, error, message);
                }
            });
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'Login page url';
        }
    }
}
```

and inside your html page call that function:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        handleButtonClick(@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the correct syntax if this JS function is inside a separate .js file?
It doesn't seem to like the syntax at all :(

Comment: I moved this code block to the View itself and it worked. This logic is shared by multiple views, so I prefer to have it in its own .js file, but I can copy/paste for now.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to pass bool value to your external js file which indicate we there user is authenticated or not. put click code inside function pass bool value to that fucntion.

Comment: Thank you! Another question if you don't mind - How do I put the user back to the same step as if he had been authenticated previously? In other words, pop-up the DateTime Kendo window after he logs in.
Right now, I can redirect the user back to the same page after he logs in, but he'll have to click the button again to invoke the code  inside the "isAuthenticated" block.

Comment: You have to send another parameter to login page which indicate after user login and redirect, DateTime Kendo window can be opened automatically or not. pass parameter to Login Controller, from Login Controller to Page Controller and from Page Controller to View and finally to Javascript code which determine popup should be opened or not.

Comment: This solution is flawed. The server-side construct for @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is evaluated when the html is served up and will not be re-evaluated without refreshing the page. If the authentication token expires between the time the page is served and the user clicks the button, this will still allow them to perform the action. What's worse, the script can be modified on the client prior to them clicking the button. The only way to truly handle authentication is on the server. I would not recommend this method unless you are in a controlled environment, such as a local intranet.

Comment: So write two external javascript file one for authenticated user and another one for unauthenticated user. @if `(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){<script src="auth.js"></script>}else{<script src="unauth.js"></script>}`

Comment: It doesn't matter how many script files you write, it doesn't solve the problem. Load page - authenticate. Token expires, you are no longer authenticated on the _server_ but the html markup says you are. Click button - action is allowed because User.Identity.IsAuthenticated was determined when the page was _loaded_. It will not be evaluated again, unless you hit F5. You have to check authentication in the controller, _not_ on the client.

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is serverside function and while razor code being complied authenticate function will be called and it will be checked with server, not in client side. If i'm wrong so you can blame Microsoft.

Comment: There is no bug in the Microsoft code. Your understanding of how User.Identity.IsAuthenticated works is correct; however, your understanding of how it works with client-side javascript is incorrect. But I am clearly unable to explain it properly without creating a full demonstration. There is a flaw in this solution, and I expect you will see it some day. Have a +1 from me to show no hard feelings.

Comment: :-) +1 does not really matter to me, I just want help. So could you tell me what is correct way to authenticate user in client side ?

Comment: There is no correct way to authenticate users on client-side, it has to be done on the server. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/11085769#11085769) example. In your code, the server validates (on page load), then sends the status to the client, but does not authenticate after pressing the button. In the example I linked, the authentication takes place both before the button is clicked (on page load), and also _after_ the button is clicked via the Authorize attribute. The Authorize attribute after ajax get/post is the key.