# How to get authorized mvc webpage via javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an MVC page that I want to take the contents of and put into a div on a WebForms page using javascript. I've done this once before without any problem, except when I did it before the MVC page allowed anonymous access.

Is there a way to pass on the logged in user's credentials in order to access an MVC page whose action has the [Authorized] attribute?

Comment: Is the WebForms and mvc page in the same project?

Comment: @gerdi Yes they are.

Comment: Isnt the logged user data stored in a cookie though, which means you shouldnt have to pass an authorize. _Sorry i have never worked with a hybrid site before_

Comment: @gerdi It works that way with redirects, but a javascript call doesn't include the cookie. I found this though that I think will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc