# POSTing Ajax form using [Authorize] attribute after the user is logged out ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, authorize-attribute, authorize

## Intro

I am building a WebApp for a client using ASP.NET MVC in C#.

I have an Ajax form within a modal window, that gets submitted when the user clicks a button.

The user has to be logged in, in order to be on this particular page and do this particular action - so I'm using the `[Authorize]` attribute for the necessary controller actions.

Let's say the controller action the form is POSTing to looks like this *(psuedo-code, just an example)*:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoAjaxThings(string field, string anotherfield)
{
    // ... do things
    if (success)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, error = "Something went wrong" });
    }
}
```

As you can see I return a Json object back with a `success` property and an `error` if necessary.

This is then handled by the callback method in the page, and off it goes to show spinners and unicorns and other magic.

If successful, the modal is closed and a "success" message is shown.

If not successful and an error is returned, an error `div` is filled with the error message I send back. Sounds fairly straightforward?..

---

## Scenario

Let's say the user's session token only lasts 15 minutes - and is sliding (*each new request resets it (not necessarily vital to the question)*). They're not using the "remember me" option.

If they've been idle/sitting on a page for more than the allotted time, then the token runs out.

Obviously, by this point their session token has expired, and they will need to log in again.

Usual behaviour would occur when navigating to `[Authorize]` controller actions: taking the user back to the Login page, with the `ReturnUrl=xyz` query string.

---

## Imagine This

So, back to the modal's Ajax form.

User has been on the page for 15 minutes, and their token has now expired.

They click the button to perform the `[Authorize]`d action...

The the Action method is not executed, and the WebApp returns a redirect to the Login page.

**But** what is returned through this Ajax call is the ENTIRE Login page. And seeing as there is no `success`, the callback function receives the redirect, which squashes the Login page - all into this one little *tiny* `div`.

You don't need me to tell you that this looks fudging hideous.

---

## Question

It is clear to see that WebApp realises the `[Authorize]` attribute and that the user is logged out.

I can't hit any breakpoints inside the Action, because the `[Authorize]` takes over and redirects automatically.

So, what I ask is this:

How can I bypass/overcome/solve this issue with the `[Authorize]` being triggered first and the Action code block not being executed?

Your kind suggestions, answers and general guidance are appreciated, as always.

Comment: check this answer [redirects to login if unauthorized ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the [Authorize] attribute, check the authorization in your controller method (`if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`), and return a suitable error to the client if the user is not authorized.

Comment: Thanks @Joe! - I'm sure at one point I did contemplate this. Are there any implications to using this way? Or is it that the `[Authorize]` uses the same check, just higher up; hence not hitting the method? I'll give it a try when I'm back in my office :)

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you so much @Joe. Could you tell me; is this basically the same check that `[Authorize]` uses in reflection higher up? I don't think there are any implications, are there?

Comment: @GeoffJames - yes, it's the same check, and there are no real implications.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom attribute, so you can redirect them to the login controller, to whatever you want to do.what I did is return them to my accessdenied action. thru ajax redirect when an ajax onerror occurs.

```
  public class ApiAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        Error = "NotAuthorized",
                        LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("AccessDenied", "Login")
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

check this answer [redirects to login if unauthorized ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

If you will observe in the network tab, you will see that the despite the status code being a `200`, the server responds with `X-Responded-JSON` which can be parsed to get the actual server status code response which is `401` in this case so you can handle the response from the `Authorize` attribute in your `AJAX` call like this in your `.cshtml` View file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: myData,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //For handling 401 with Authorize attribute on Controller
        if (xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Responded-JSON") != null && JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Responded-JSON")).status == "401") {
            alert("Unauthorized access returned by Controller");
            //Will redirect to login page
            location.reload(true);
        }
        else {
            alert("Still Authorized");
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("There was a technical error");
        console.log(err)
    },
});
```