# In ASP Net Core 3.1 Expiration cookie is not redirecting to login page when using ajax

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-ajax

In my app, when my cookie expire, I'm redirect to my Account/Login page. But When I call ajax method and cookie is expired , the action return 401 and I'm not redirecting to my Account/login page...

I add [Authorize] attribute on my controller.

The xhr.status parameter return 401.

Example ajax method :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.ajax-modal', function (event) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-content');
    if (id != null)
        url = url + '/' + id;
    $.get(url)
        .done(
            function (data) {
               placeholderElement.html(data);
               placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
            }
        )
        .fail(
            function (xhr, httpStatusMessage, customErrorMessage) {
                selectErrorPage(xhr.status);
            }
        );
});
```

My ConfigureServices method :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region Session
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // permet d'empecher à du code JS d'accèder aux cookies
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Cookie

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "TestCookie";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/login";
                    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                });

        #endregion
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344665/handling-session-timeout-with-ajax-in-net-core-mvc) may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the issue where I am using cookie authentication in .NET Core 5, yet once the user is authenticated, everything BUT any initial AJAX request in the application works.

Every AJAX request would result in a 401. Even using the jQuery load feature would result in a 401, which was just a GET request to a controller with the [Authorize(Role = "My Role")]

However, I found that I could retrieve the data if I grabbed the URL directly and pasted it in the browser. Then suddenly, all my AJAX worked for the life of the cookie. I noticed the difference in some of the AJAX posts. The ones that didn't work used AspNetCore.AntiForgery in the headers, whereas the ones that did use AspNetCore.Cookies that authenticated.

My fix was to add a redirect in the OnRedirectToLogin event under cookie authentication. It works for all synchronous and asynchronous calls ensuring that AJAX redirects to the login page and authenticates as the current user. I don't know if this is the proper way to handle my issue, but here is the code.

EDIT: I should mention that all of the AJAX code worked perfectly in my .NET 4 web application. When I changed to 5, I experienced new issues.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(o => {
                  o.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
              o.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
              o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
              o.SlidingExpiration = true;
              //add this to force and request to redirect (my purpose AJAX not going to login page on request and authenticating)
              o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) => { 
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
              };
            });
```