# How do I automatically redirect when the session cookie expires?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

When a user is idle for ten minutes, I would like to have an automatic redirect. Below is the test code, which is not working.

The `LoginPath`, `LogoutPath`, and `AccessDeniedPath` do not exist. Therefore, I would expect an error after the timeout period. Instead, I can continue to successfully click "Home" and "About" without an error and without being redirected. My expectation is that I will be redirected back to the home page.

Sample code:

```cs
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppCookie";
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });

           
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

Comment: If the pages are missing, I wouldn't expect that this would redirect to the homepage. Instead, I'd expect that it would redirect to the target pages, but yield a 404 error. Obviously, that's not happening, and thus your question. But your expectation infers a second question which is a bit tangential to your main issue (e.g., "How can I route 404 errors to my homepage?").

Comment: The main question is why did the auto redirect not get triggered on a cookie time out. The 404 expectation is for visual confirmation on the Hello World  app. There would be no doubt that the auto redirect has been triggered by the cookie time out.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, and I think that is clear in the original question. It's just the last sentence in your second paragraph that I find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, your code can know about the session timeout. Using it, you can set a cookie indicating when the actual session timeout occurred (no mention of whether it was an active session timeout or an idle timeout). The javascript running on the page can periodically read the cookie and redirect the user when the timeout value is exceeded.

This is one of many methods that I hope will help you.

Refer this post ：

[In ASP Net Core 3.1 Expiration cookie is not redirecting to login page when using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210767/in-asp-net-core-3-1-expiration-cookie-is-not-redirecting-to-login-page-when-usin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axios interceptors for them, in the first request after token expiration you can redirect it.
Also, you can decode your token at [https://jwt.io/][1] and take the expiration date, you can check by it.